# Displaying Two Form Buttons Inline

Tags: html, css

I've got two form buttons like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Post"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
```

They are displaying one below each other.

How can I display them inline?

Comment: I think there is more going on then just what you posted. That part would display inline just fine. Perhaps there is something in your css that makes them behave otherwise.

Comment: Please post the rest of the relevant HTML and CSS, as @gnur says, there's more going on here. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/HAHPT/

Comment: It's alright, I've got the problem.  As you all mentioned, the problem was in the css which I'm using to style the form elements.  Thanks you all!

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, for other users :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has to be something wrong with your CSS as [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)'s are not block elements

and, as you can [see in this example](http://jsbin.com/irawi4/edit), (click in the [Preview button](http://jsbin.com/irawi4)) the simple plain html shows them inline

Comment: link is broken, perhaps edit your answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
<span style="display: inline;">
  <input type="submit" value="Post"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQ7xv/

Answer (score 3):

try   `style="display:inline;"` :)

Answer (score 2):

So, first you should put both inputs in a div,
then add `display: flex;` to the div.

html:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
     <input type="submit" value="Post"/> 
     <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
</div>
```