# About ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application

Tags: css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I need to add some CSS to the `Register` and `Login` buttons in `[partial name="_LoginPartial"]` tag in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app project. How could I do that?

I have tried to make them (`Register` and `Login`) inline but that didn't work. I have tried to add ids and classes to the partial name tag and add css to them, and tried to add the following way by asking chatGPT

```
<a href="@Url.Action("_LoginPartial", "/identity/Account/Register")" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">Register</a>

<a href="@Url.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account")" class="btn btn-outline-success float-right">Login</a>
```

That didn't work either

Comment: please show all related codes,It's hard to know what got wrong with the codes you provided

Comment: This case may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040935/displaying-two-form-buttons-inline